# How to pass data from one view to another view in iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I want to pass int or string data from one view to another, please help me

```
NSUInteger i1 = [array indexOfObject:username];
SSPUserLogedInViewController *logInView = [[SSPUserLogedInViewController alloc] init];
logInView.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;
[self presentViewController:logInView animated:YES completion:nil];
```

I am able to next view but not able to pass the data.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create a variable for your passing data into your next view.
2. Using an
       instance of the next view, access the variable that you have created
       in next view
3. assign your value to the variable

For Ex in your case;

1. Suppose you want to pass the value of an int

   In Next view controller: copy this in `**.h**` file

> @property (assign) int temp;

2.
 SSPUserLogedInViewController *logInView =
    [[SSPUserLogedInViewController alloc] init];
    >

```
    logInView.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;
```

> ```
>         logInView.temp = <YOUR_VALUE>
>         [self presentViewController:logInView animated:YES completion:nil];
> ```

1. In Next view controller: copy this in `**.m**` file

> -(void)viewWillAppear
>
> {
>
> ```
>    NSLog(@"My Value = %i",_temp);
> ```
>
> }

Enjoy Programming!!

Comment: its  giving me error on step 1
"property with retain must be of object type"

Comment: did you write @property (assign) int temp; only?

Comment: no, i did everything..

Comment: property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *userLabel;
    property (strong, nonatomic) NSString * text;

    property (assign) int temp;

Comment: i also put @ in front of everyline
this website show me error in above comments

Comment: Follow like this 
property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *userLabel;
property (strong, nonatomic) NSString * text; 
property (nonatomic) int temp;

Comment: Yes i wrote "@" before property

Comment: And yes do include "@" before every line

Answer (score 0):

Write some function like `- (void)doSomeThing:(NSString) data` in your`SSPUserLogedInViewController` class

and call

```
[logInView doSomeThing:yourDetails];
```

after

`SSPUserLogedInViewController *logInView = [[SSPUserLogedInViewController alloc] init];`

Answer (score 0):

define NSMutableString *string; with property in the SSPUserLogedInViewController class. alloc init in view did load. You can set string like this.

```
NSString *i1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
SSPUserLogedInViewController *logInView = [[SSPUserLogedInViewController alloc] init];
[logInView.string setString:i1];
logInView.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;
[self presentViewController:logInView animated:YES completion:nil];
```