# How to select ViewController?

Tags: ios, ios7, viewcontroller, navigationcontroller

1. The app starts on ViewContoller
2. I push TutoViewContoller
3. On some action, I pop TutoViewContoller

I would like to call a method of ViewContoller just after popping TutoViewController. How can I do that ?

Comment: Call that method in viewwillappear: method of viewcontroller

Comment: I don't want it to be called everytime the view appears. I want want it to be called after popping TutoViewController.

Comment: ok, then maintain one bool prefrence by default set it to 'No' and when it goes to TutoViewController set it to 'yes' and check that preference in viewwillappear of viewcontroller

Comment: there are 2 options for that. first is use NSNotificationCenter and second is use delegate. for delegate see this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18566304/sending-data-from-one-viewcontroller-to-another

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement viewWillAppear of ViewController. If you really need to distinguish between TutoViewController and other viewcontroller you have many options to call before you pop it: delegate pattern, passing reference of ViewController to TutoViewController etc.

Comment: ... also `NSNotificationCenter`