# Questions on core data

Tags: ios

I am starting to develop core data database and i do have a few questions that I can,t understand. Can any one please explain in brief and please keep it simple.

1)

```
NSManagedObject *employee=[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Employee" inManagedObjectContext:_managedObjectContext];
    [employee setValue:self.empnametextfield.text forKey:@"empname"];
    [employee setValue:self.empidtextfield.text forKey:@"empid"];
```

while saving the data into database into the database i use this code. But why I am creating instances of NSManagedObject & NsentityDescription?

2)

```
    _fetchrequest=[[NSFetchRequest alloc]init];
        NSEntityDescription *entity=[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Employee" inManagedObjectContext:_managedObjectContext];
        [_fetchrequest setEntity:entity];
 NSError *error;
    _fetchedobjects=[_managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:_fetchrequest error:&error];
```

And when i fetch data i use this coding. So my question is why do i use the instance of NSEntity description here?

3)What is the difference between the purposes for which we use "NSEntityDescription" while in saving & fetching data?

Please answer the above 3 questions of mine as I am quite stuck in it?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Stuck how? What do you think they are? What have you read about them?

Comment: Sir,I have read about them but how do they function in the program what are their importance & how do they work. I just can't understand.

Answer (score 0):

When you build your core data stack you load a model which describes the data structure objects and relationships. This is built in terms of entity descriptions. They hold the format for the data, the names, types, multiplicities and rules associated. Without this you have no structure, you might as well just have a generic `NSSet`.

So, when you're doing operations on the data structure, creating new entity instances or querying, you need to get the description of the entity you're working with so the system knows the rules to work with.

Comment: in my part of saving data i don't use any instance of nsentitydescription but why do i use an instance of the same while fetching data.

Comment: When you create the managed object you use the entity name and it finds the description for you. You can do a similar thing with the fetch is you use `+ fetchRequestWithEntityName:`