# Can I announce a class method in an Objective-C protocol?

Tags: objective-c

How can I announce a class method in protocal?
I have tried like this:

```
@protocal
+(void)methodA;
@end;
```

but this leads to crash.

Comment: Where is it crashing? How are you implementing the protocol?

Comment: If you want to call a class method, you dont need to define as a protocol method, you should directly call it.

Comment: @ParasGorasiya That's not correct.

Comment: Below link might be useful to you how to declare a class method https://stackoverflow.com/a/33036150/5184217

Comment: Where is the Protocol Name?

Answer (score 0):

If your intent is to specify a class method that conforming classes must implement, then, yes, you can define class methods in your protocol requirements.

But your protocol needs a name. And `@protocol` was misspelled.

```
@protocol ProtocolNameHere
+(void)methodA;
@end
```